# Dynamic menu with jQuery json data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I have tried this but it doesn't work. I'm trying to make Dynamic Menu from jQuery json data. I have insert preview below.

I'm working on fully custom UI, so I plan not to use jQuery.UI.

```js
var data = {
        menu: [{
            name: 'Women Cloth',
            link: '0',
            sub: null
        },{
            name: 'Men Cloth',
            link: '1',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Arsenal',
                link: '0-0',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Liverpool',
                link: '0-1',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Manchester United',
                link: '0-2',
                sub: null
            }]
        }]};

    var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li>", {
            class: 'has-children',
            id: itemData.id
        }).append(
        $("<a>", {
            href: itemData.link,
            html: itemData.name,
            id: itemData.id + '-links',
        }));
        if (itemData.sub) {
            var subMenuItem = $("<li>", {
            class: 'has-icon'
            }).append(
            $("<a>", {
                href: itemData.link,
                class: 'submenu-title',
            }));
            var subList = $("<ul>", {
                class: 'secondary-dropdown',
            });
            $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
                subList.append(subMenuItem(this));
            });
            item.append(subList);
        }
        return item;
    };
    var $menu = $("#Menu");
    $.each(data.menu, function () {
        $menu.append(
            getMenuItem(this)
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Menu"></ul>
```

Below is the output I needed.

```
<li class="has-children" id="ID">
    <a id="ID-links" href="links">Women Clothing</a>
    <ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li class="go-back"><a>Back</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 1</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 2</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 3</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 4</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="has-children" id="ID">
    <a id="ID-links" href="links">Men Clothing</a>
    <ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li class="go-back"><a>Back</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 1</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 2</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 3</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 4</a></li>
        <li class="has-icon"><a class="submenu">submenu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not using `$.each` function as you were supposed. you are passing `this` as `args` to your function. `this` will `undefined` in the function `getMenuItem`

In you $.each  function you need to have args as index and data. `Index` return the number of each `key` in you `JSON` & `data` is the one you need to pass to your function.

Also in your `cd-secondary-dropdown` you need to add `ul` only **once** and not in `$.each`.

I have fixed up your `code` and is exactly working as you wanted in your output above.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
var data = {
  menu: [{
    name: 'Women Cloth',
    link: '0',
    sub: null
  }, {
    name: 'Men Cloth',
    link: '1',
    sub: [{
      name: 'Arsenal',
      link: '0-0',
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: 'Liverpool',
      link: '0-1',
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: 'Manchester United',
      link: '0-2',
      sub: null
    }]
  }]
};

var getMenuItem = function(itemData) {

  var item = $("<li>", {
    class: 'has-children',
    id: itemData.id
  }).append(
    $("<a>", {
      href: itemData.link,
      html: itemData.name,
      id: itemData.id + '-links',
    }));


  if (itemData.sub) {
    //Add UL once only
    var subList = $("<ul>", {
      class: 'secondary-dropdown',
    }); 
    //Append go back
    var goBack = $("<li>", {}).append(
      $("<a>", {
        href: '',
        html: 'Go back',
        class: 'go-back',
      }));
    //Append go back
    subList.append(goBack);
    $.each(itemData.sub, function(index, data) {
      //Sub menu
      var subMenuItem = $("<li>", {
        class: 'has-icon'
      }).append(
        $("<a>", {
          href: data.link,
          html: data.name,
          class: 'submenu-title',
        }));

      subList.append(subMenuItem);
    });

    item.append(subList);
  }
  return item;
};


var $menu = $("#Menu");
$.each(data.menu, function(index, data) {
  $menu.append(getMenuItem(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Menu"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi, how about the go-back li that i mention about with the aspected output.

Comment: one more question, if i want to calculate the height. for example, $('.has-children') height = 240px / (how many main categories items)

Comment: @Kelvin you need to divide `/` by the `.length` of the total categories. Would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please if i have helped and solved your question ?

Comment: @Kelvin You can try using `.length` like:  `$('.has-children') height() ` / `$('.main-categories').length` -  This is just rough example only. But this week you can achieve this!. Ideally i would suggest if you can post another question add add `main-categories` html - so someone can help with the exact

Comment: actually is the same, just calculate how many <li class="has-children" id="ID">, from the code above, Women's Cloth and Men Cloth is Main Categories.

Comment: @Kelvin Sorry but its not clear what you are want to with height and divide with what. Ideally please add another question and add the requirements this way you will have more exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are trying to do? if yes, this is a way of doing it without jQuery

```js
let data = {
        menu: [{
            name: 'Women Cloth',
            link: '0',
            sub: null
        },{
            name: 'Men Cloth',
            link: '1',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Arsenal',
                link: '0-0',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Liverpool',
                link: '0-1',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Manchester United',
                link: '0-2',
                sub: null
            }]
        }]};

const MENU_COMPONENT  = document.querySelector('#Menu');

for (const field in data.menu) {


const LI= document.createElement('li');
LI.setAttribute('class', 'has-children');
MENU_COMPONENT.appendChild(LI);
const LINK = document.createElement('a');
LINK.setAttribute('href', data.menu[field].link);
LINK.innerText = data.menu[field].name;
LI.appendChild(LINK);

const UL = document.createElement('ul');
UL.setAttribute('class', 'cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden');
LI.appendChild(UL);

let SUBLEVEL_DATA = data.menu[field].sub;

  for (const sub in SUBLEVEL_DATA) {
    const SECOND_LEVEL_LI = document.createElement('li');
    SECOND_LEVEL_LI.setAttribute('class', 'has-icon');
    UL.appendChild(SECOND_LEVEL_LI);
    const SECOND_LEVEL_LINK = document.createElement('a');
    SECOND_LEVEL_LINK.setAttribute('href', SUBLEVEL_DATA[sub].link);
    SECOND_LEVEL_LINK.className = 'submenu';
         SECOND_LEVEL_LINK.innerText = SUBLEVEL_DATA[sub].name;
     SECOND_LEVEL_LI.appendChild(SECOND_LEVEL_LINK);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="Menu"></ul>
```

Comment: how about the go-back li that i mention about with the aspected output.